# How to change locale in Ubuntu Core?

Tags: ubuntu-core

On freshly installed Ubuntu Core 16 for Raspberry Pi 3, calling `locale` prints:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

I'm assuming some of those values are set by ssh client.

How to generate new locale? I cannot find `locale-gen` and there is no `locales` package.

Comment: Have you tried putting `export LANG=locale` in your `~/.profile` file, with the word locale being the locale you want to use? Usually changing just the lang is good enough. Also, have you looked into using the `setlocale` command?

Comment: I cannot find `setlocale` in PATH, a least non in the base image for raspberrypi. I can set the locales using env variables, but there only seem to be one possible value, that is `C.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Ubuntu Core ships without locale support; `/etc/default/locale` in core is readonly, hardwired to `C.UTF-8`.

There exists a `locale-control` interface that is for use *on classic*, that is, it allows a snap to control the default locale of a classic system. It does not work on an ubuntu core system.

Comment: can you please reference any document that states that? I've found a plug called `locale-control` listed [here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/reference/interfaces) - do you think it is related to locales or something else?

Comment: @chrmod I've expanded my answer addressing `locale-control` and giving a bit more detail.